# is .htaccess is good for creating yii admin panel?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I am creating an application with Yii Framework and want to redirect http://mydomain.com/yiiframework to http://mydomain.com/yiiframework/default so i created .htaccess file and i put this content on it but it don't redirect anything :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /default/index.php [L]
```

my questions are :

1 - what is wrong in my htaccess file ?

2 - is that a good way to create admin section and put other stuff in default folder ?

**Edited :**

I accidently find it out ,i changed .htaccess to this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$  http://mydomain.com/yiiframework/default/index.php
```

and it server my purpose , but the mystery is :

> ^$

shows the start of line and the end of the line , what this Regular Expressions means?

Comment: are you sure .htaccess is enabled on your server?

Comment: yes ,i put redirect command on htaccess and it worked.

Comment: So you want to redirect everything to `/default/index.php` ? If so, why ?

Comment: I was thinking to use RewriteRule because redirect command repeat itself and make /default/default/... and so on .

Comment: @RezaMarefaty Hmmm I still don't get the purpose. Whatever, `[L]` means to not process any more rules if this line is used. I tried `RewriteEngine On {NEWLINE REMOVE THIS} RewriteRule . /default/index.php [L]` and it works for me.

Comment: I edit the question ,maybe it not working for my web address.

Comment: This is rewrite rules, not redirect, but you write that it does not redirect. Here is guide for yii htaccess: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/ Also, your files layout is www.example.com/default/index.php ? If so, make sure you place htaccess in web root, but probably it would be easier to place application in higher folder - as there might be issues with assets path (not sure about that).

Answer (score -1):

to create admin-panel best practice is to create separate application for backend and frontend, which share common things with fontend, backend as in this boilerplate,https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBoilerplate

or

you sholud create single application and devide it into modules, each module have code for both frontend and backend as you see this in many yii based open source applications like [Zurmo](https://github.com/yupe/yupe), [Yupe CMS](https://github.com/yupe/yupe), [X2Engine](https://github.com/X2Engine/X2Engine),

i would prefer second approach which is modular and maintainable code, slightly hard but best